# spring4, jboss eap 6.4.0 xlsx file upload corrupted size

Tags: excel, spring, jboss, upload, xlsx

I've problems with file upload in Spring4 application.

**tl;dr**

After .xlsx file upload, we have bigger file than original. In additional, we can't open it with Microsoft Office.

**Problem**

I've checked every tutorial, made implementation in every single way. It's working as well with almost every file types except XLSX.

**Scenario**

I am using file (for example, first from http://www.sample-videos.com/download-sample-xls.php)

In terminal:

```
$ ls -la | grep .xlsx
-rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff    19K 31 mar 13:46 SampleXLSFile_19kb.xlsx
```

*19kb*

But after upload, I have:

```
$ ls -la | grep .xlsx
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff    24K 31 mar 13:47 SampleXLSFile_19kb.xlsx
```

*whaaat!? 24K?*

After debugging, I've reached point that file is located in Jboss temp directory with new, bigger size.

**What's the problem?**

I can't open .xslx file in excel after upload, I can't process them in application. File is broken.

Do you have any ideas?
As I can see, there is problem ONLY with xlsx files.

Example upload code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/file", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(new File(this.uploadDirectory + "/" + file.getOriginalFilename())));
            FileCopyUtils.copy(file.getInputStream(), stream);
            stream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }
    return new ResponseEntity(null, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

As you can see - nothing special.

**@UPDATE**

It looks like there is no issue with .xslx files only. There is issue with binary files as well.

I've discovered, that `org/apache/commons/fileupload/MultipartStream.java` is causing this issue. It looks like its read too much bytes from in and save much bigger files.
For example, I've uploaded 43M zip file but at the end, I get 78M uploaded zip file.

**@SOLVED**

It turned out that it was some internal app issue. We had one spring filter which managed current request to extract some data to log. The filter was running quite early, so upload mechanism get corrupted data from our filter.

Comment: I don't understand much of this. However I notice that you talk about two different file types:XLS and XLSX.

Comment: @DougGlancy thanks! That was a typo.

Comment: And I've changed post. I hope, now is much more clear.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck. I wish I could offer something else.